# Can AJAX HTTP request send cookies that are not set on the client?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

So imagine I want to send a request that acts like I was logged on even thought I'm not. This means use cookie that is not set in the document.

Can this be done? My site uses `jQuery`, but raw javascript alternative would be preferred for non-jQuery users. Also I suppose extra problems appear with CORS.

Comment: A cookie can not be set and unset at the same time, so what do you exactly want?
If I understand you correct it might be possible to create a cookie, do the request and then destroy the cookie, but I'm not sure if this would work.

Comment: Yes it can be and its actually a security issue called session hijacking.

Comment: Session hijacking is something else. We call session hijacking when malicious script in user's browser retrieves his session cookie and sends it to somewhere else. This is quite not what I'm talking about.